# Traverse up to base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I can do the following to get the name of the class I am using with an instance:

```
self.__class__.__name__
```

Is there a way to get the base class name without going beyond into any of the django built-in types? If so, how could that be done? For example if I have:

```
class Wire:
    def __init__(self, default=True):
        self.state = default
        self.observers = []


class LED(Wire):
    """
    For debugging."""
```

How could I get (without knowing how many levels of inheritance there might be)?:

```
>>> l = LED()
>>> l.get_base_case() # 'Wire'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mro()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.mro) on the object's type:

```
type(l).mro()[1]  # 0: the type itself, 1: base class in linear hierarchy, ...
```

Here *mro* stands for *method resolution order*.

Comment: That doesn't help with the OP's intent to ascend an undetermined way up the hierarchy (ignoring the further complexity introduced by multiple inheritance).

Comment: @chepner If it's really undetermined then that's not going to be very useful. IIUC they either want to get the direct base class (index `1`) or the "oldest" one (index `-2`). That should all work in a single inheritance schema. If multiple inheritance is involved, things become much more complex indeed (though this was not mentioned in the OP).

Comment: They specifically said in the answer they don't know how many levels of inheritance might be involved. The comment about "[not] going beyond into any of the django built-in types" makes me think they want to stop somewhere in the "middle" of the hierarchy.